# What is context_object_name=None in django class CreateView?

Tags: python, django

> Get the name to use for the object. For context_object_name=None

Doc:For example Article will be article
Why we use context_object_name in createview.We don't have a object,we just have a simple form to show users.

```
def get_context_object_name(self, obj):
    """Get the name to use for the object."""
    if self.context_object_name:
        return self.context_object_name
    elif isinstance(obj, models.Model):
        return obj._meta.model_name
    else:
        return None
```

Please somebody help me???

Comment: I hope the doc itself self-explanatory - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name

Answer (score 1):

In any class based view, the default object name, in case of a single object is `object` and in case of multiple objects is `object_list`. These are the context variables you use in your template that renders the view.

For example, in case of a single object, you will use them as

```
{{object}}
...
{{object.pk}}
```

and in case of multiple items:

```
{% for i in object_list %}
...do something...
{% endfor %}
```

When you supply a `context_object_name` in your view, the variable named `object` will be replaced by that.

For example: If you set `context_object_name='place'`, then in your template, you can use the instance as `{{place}}` instead of `{{object}}`

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts

Comment: Why in form template output nothing....

Comment: Forms are accessed via `{{form}}` in the template. More reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options

Comment: No,How can retrieve object in form.html

Comment: When creating, the object is accessible through `form.instance`, you can access that object inside `form_valid` method.

As far as I can check, `CreateView` does not use the `get_context_object_name` method. This method is inherited from `SingleObjectMixin`, which is subclassed by `ModelFormMixin`, which is then subclassed by `BaseCreateView` which is then subclassed by `CreateView`.

So, typically every `GenericView` class has this method, only difference being it is not used by some views, like `CreateView`.